# How to use different column values from other table based on value on current table column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table A with  [agent name] and [conducted by] columns

[image]

I have an another table B with [Agent Names],[Manager] and [SDI] columns

[image]

I need a result like the table below

[image]

result table is based on table A  and Table B .If the [Conducted by] field value in Table A is 0 then i need to get [manager] column value from table B,else if my [conducted by] column value in table A is 1 then i need to get [SDI] column value from table B.how can i achieve this?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: `select ... case when [conducted by]=1 then manager else sdi end`, basically?

Comment: You might want to look into normalization. Storing names in more than 1 table is going to cause nothing but pain in the long run. Read up about normalization and make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  a.agentName,
  CASE
    WHEN a.conductedBy=0 THEN b.manager
    ELSE b.sdi
  END AS conductedBy
FROM tableA AS a
JOIN tableB AS b ON a.agentName=b.agentName
```

or this:

```
SELECT
  a.agentName,
  CASE a.conductedBy
    WHEN 0 THEN b.manager
    ELSE b.sdi
  END AS conductedBy
FROM tableA AS a
JOIN tableB AS b ON a.agentName=b.agentName
```

only for mysql work this:

```
SELECT
  a.agentName,
  IF(a.conductedBy=0, b.manager, b.sdi) AS conductedBy
FROM tableA AS a
JOIN tableB AS b ON a.agentName=b.agentName
```

Comment: IF clause inside a SELECT QUERY. Great idea but wont work in SQLServer till 2014 Version.

Comment: Sorry, that I have overlooked

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `case` statement:

```
case when ConductedBy = 0 then [Manager] when ConductedBy = 1 then [SDI] end
```